# What is the correct method for accessing the exports object in a TabViewItem?

Tags: nativescript

```
<Page xmlns:tsk="pages/task" xmlns:trnr="pages/turner" loaded="loaded" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar>
        <ActionBar.actionItems>
            <ActionItem text="Add" ios.position="right" android.position="popup" tap="addTabTapped" />
        </ActionBar.actionItems>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>
<TabView>
    <TabView.items>
        <TabViewItem title="Turners">
            <TabViewItem.view>
                <trnr:turner-list-page />
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
        <TabViewItem title="Task">
            <TabViewItem.view>
                <tsk:task-list-page />
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView.items>
</TabView>
</Page>
```

I have a TabView xml page that contains custom xml components as TabViewItems.  Each of these components has a code behind page with navigatingTo methods as exports.  In my TabView `loaded` method, I have a handler that sets the currently selected TabViewItem "onSelectedIndexChange".  When the user is navigated around the application, and back to the TabView page, the navigatingTo that is invoked is in the TabView, not in the TabViewItems.  I have tried to place the navigatingTo in various spots in the TabView xml page, but the navigatingTo only seems to be called for the page, *not* the custom xml components.

I see when debugging and watching the TabViewItem that the exports object is available, and that the exports of each TabViewItem are accessible, but when I try to invoke those methods from within my code, they do *not* seem to be accessible.

Is there a means of accessing the export object on a TabViewItem so that the exported methods within the various tab view items can be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

So I have successfully managed to answer my own question:

In my loaded function:

```
export function loaded(args:EventData) {
    var page:Page = <Page>args.object;
    var tv:tabView.TabView = <tabView.TabView>page.content;
    tv.on(tabView.TabView.selectedIndexChangedEvent, handleTabChange);
    selectedTabViewItem = tv.items[tv.selectedIndex];
};
```

I set a reference to the selected tab view item.

Then to reference the exports method, it is as simple as

```
selectedTabViewItem.view["exports"].addTapped(args);
```

Anything that is exported can now be accessed from anything referencing that view.